# Overscan compensation issue

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, display, resolution

Since upgrading to 12.10 I cant permanently fix overscan on my tv.

Using this code I can fix the overscan

```
sudo nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1: 1920x1080 { ViewPortOut=1850x1045+40+20, ViewPortIn=1920x1080 }
```

But on 12.04 I would simply add this command to startup apps and it would work fine but this does not seem to work on 12.10.

Any suggestions ?

ps I have to enter this code twice in terminal because the first time turns my desktop background black and hides all open windows, but new one will still show up.

Comment: 1) You should not have to run `nvidia-settings` with `sudo`. 2) How would this work as a startup command whenever `sudo` asks for a password? 3) Is the quoting at only one end of the command intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*diclaimer: this should work by reading the manpages, but I'm not able to test this at this moment*

1. Create a `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` file, containing/adding

   ```
   CurrentMetaMode=DFP-1: 1920x1080 { ViewPortOut=1850x1045+40+20, ViewPortIn=1920x1080 }
   ```

   Alternatively, run

   ```
   nvidia-settings --rewrite-config-file
   ```

   to overwrite the `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` file with the current state of the X Server settings configuration.
2. Then edit/create your `~/.xinitrc` file:

   ```
   nvidia-settings --load-config-only &
   ```

   To load the settings from the RC file after logging in as that user.

For more information, read the manpage `nvidia-settings(1)`.