# Ubuntu 12.04 NVIDIA card overscan on HDMI HDTV

Tags: nvidia, xorg, hdmi, hdtv

I have a GT 430 Nvidia, was working fine till I upgraded to 12.04 yesterday. Apparently, nvidia decided to remove the overscan slider. I can't adjust to fix the overscan then, except in the xorg.conf which I can't edit. Even if I can, I'm not sure it would fix the problem.

I know the resolution that fits my TV as I have this issue in windows and in Ubuntu, its 1824x1026. Strange resolution, but it works. Is there a way I can either edit xorg.conf or if I can change it without doing so? Am running the latest drivers (not the experimental ones).

The issue with the xorg.conf is that it won't let me edit due to permission.

Comment: Very very similar question with solution: [Overscan compensation issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/237934/88802).

Answer (score 0):

xorg.conf cannot be edited without root permissions. To edit it, do this:

1. Press Alt+F2. This will open the "Run Application" window.
2. Type `gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and press Enter.
3. Enter your password when prompted and press Enter.
4. gedit will open with xorg.conf.
5. Make your modifications and press Ctrl+S to save.
6. Reboot.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me into the file, but I can't get it to use the modes I set. I've taken instead to using the terminal to manually set my resolution, I can get it almost perfect but the edge (where the power button is!) just gets cut off.